# How to handle multiple behaviors for controller actions depending on submitted parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, action, behavior

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and in a my RESTful controller I would like to handle multiple behaviors for each controller action depending on submitted parameters presence. I think that I can avoid to create a new controller because, despite the presence of parameters, the mentioned behaviors use and have effects on the same model (that is, on the same database table) and/but just the controller response data is different.

In order to handle multiple behaviors for a same controller action my proposed solution is that I can submit a "router" parameter like `behavior=1`, `behavior=2`, ... `behavior=N` so that, for example, when my application receives a request with the `behavior=1` parameter then the returned data is different than when it receives `behavior=2` or `behavior=N`. Making so, however, the controller implementation could result in a more difficult code to maintain.

What do you advice? How can/should I handle the "multiple behaviors case"? What are common tecniques and practices about? Should I create a "dedicated" controller or can I use the same controlled as proposed above?

Comment: OK, you don't want many controllers, but why not many actions?

Comment: A giant method that handles many different cases sounds like something to avoid.

Comment: @Uri Agassi - I didn't say that I don't want many controllers even many actions.

Comment: @Frederick Cheung - A "giant method" is is my "fear". Maybe there are some alternatives that I don't know...

Comment: So why not create a different action for each behavior? That is their meaning after sll

Comment: @Uri Agassi - Maybe because it is not RESTful and this can be an inconsistency. I would like to find the right balance...

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
def some_controller_action
  case params[:behavior]
  when 1
    # something for when behavior = 1
  when 2
  when 3
  when 4
  else
  end
end
```

Comment: As proposed in the question itself, it is what I am thinking about. Making so, however, the controller implementation could result in a more difficult code to maintain. Thus I posted the last sub-questions?

Comment: It is my personal opinion, but separating each case out to a controller action seems like an overkill. You can potentially create a model method that encapsulate some logic, but largely, i think this is fine.